# Count duplicate cell values as one if multiple criteria are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, distinct, sumproduct

I am trying to get the total **count** of entries **per month** based on the status ("Settled") and the **distinct code**. If the other status of the other entries in that certain code is not yet settled, it shouldn't count. Please see example below and the expected output.

```
MONTH   |CODE  |CONTRIBUTION|STATUS
JANUARY |CS-111|500         |Settled
JANUARY |CS-111|500         |Settled
FEBRUARY|CS-131|200         |Settled    
FEBRUARY|CS-131|200         |Waiting
FEBRUARY|CS-141|300         |Settled
MARCH   |CS-151|400         |Waiting
MARCH   |CS-161|700         |Settled
```

Sample output:

```
January  | 1  | 1 because same code and status
February | 1  | 1 because only CS-141 is settled, the second entry of CS-131 is Waiting
March    | 1  | 1 because only CS-161 is settled
```

This is my formula based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516598/exclude-addition-in-sumifs-if-unique-value-is-not-in-the-same-status-in-excel) question:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$8="January"),--(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,$D$2:$D$8,"Settled")=0))
```

With the formula above, I get 2 as the output for January and not 1. 1 because they have the same code and status. Could you kindly help me which concept I should apply to get the expected output? Hope my question is clear. Thank you very much.

Apologies if this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine this setup:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$8=G2)*($D$2:$D$8="Settled"),IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,$D$2:$D$8,"Waiting")=0,MATCH($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,0))),ROW($B$2:$B$8)-ROW($B$2)+1)>0))
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

Comment: Wow!! Thank you for this. I'm looking up the frequency concept to help me better understand it. However, I tried the formula on my end and when I changed the status of the first entry for January for CS-111 to Waiting, the value is still 1. It should return the value of 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes because the second one is still on settled @Isabella =)

Comment: Is there any way we could get the output of 0 if the status of the first entry in January with code CS-111 is "Waiting"? Because technically not all entries for CS-111 is settled? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Isabella, I've updated the formula to account for that scenario :). Please, if this has answered your question, consider to upvote/accept the answer to return the favor =)

Comment: Hi, @JvdV. Apologies for the late reply, I was on travel. Wow, this worked like magic. Thank you very very much!!!